# Twig templates in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, twig, laravel-blade

I would like to use TWIG templating instead for BLADE, is this possible?

Are there plans to support TWIG? As it is part of Symfony 2 and Laravel 4 relies on Symfony it would seem to be a good idea.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There exists a composer package [TwigBridge](https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge) that does exactly that.

Comment: This is an issue with TwigBridge then. Go there and report it as a bug.

Comment: 4.2 support should be fixed with the latest release.